# WCF Client config trouble

Tags: wcf

I created a WCF service in VS2010 that returns Json. I also created an Nunit test project that calls the methods of the service. All was working well when using the built-in VS2010 web server. I then configured the service to run in my local IIS6.1. I can successfully bring up the service in a browser as in `http://localhost/PVSCService/WebData.svc` but I get the famous:

> There was no endpoint listening at `http://localhost/PVSCService/WebData.svc` that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

My service web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="PVSCWeb.Service.WebData">
        <endpoint name="jsonEP"
                  address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="json"
                  contract="PVSCWeb.Service.IWebData"/>
      </service>
    </services>    
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="json">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>      
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and my Nunit test project app.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IWebData" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
              openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
              bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
              maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
              messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
              allowCookies="false">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                enabled="false" />
            <security mode="Message">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                  realm="" />
              <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                  algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
            </security>
          </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/PVSCService/WebData.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IWebData"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IWebData" name="WSHttpBinding_IWebData">
          </endpoint>
      </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <!-- This logging is great when WCF does not work. -->
    <sources>
      <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Error, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="AppFabricTracing" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="AppFabricTracing" initializeData="c:\PVSCService.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

I have noticed the suggestions regarding turning off Windows Firewall but network policy forbids that. I've tried adding in the correct endpoint address :

```
<endpoint name="jsonEP"
          address="http://localhost/PVSCService/WebData.svc"
          binding="webHttpBinding"
          behaviorConfiguration="json"
          contract="PVSCWeb.Service.IWebData"/>
```

But this creates another error regarding multiple site bindings. Seems like I'm missing something simple but critical. Thanks in advance, any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show us the contents of the `WebData.svc` file?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your WCF service uses the `webHttpBinding` which is the one to use for REST services.

However, your **NUnit** config uses `wsHttpBinding` which is wrong here - that's a **SOAP** binding and it's **NOT** compatible with `webHttpBinding`. You need to change the NUnit config to also use `webHttpBinding`